# Making Copies of a Master Sheet and Naming them according to a value in a list on a separate Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am not sure why this is not working.  Code breaks on line 3!

I have a count formula on the sheet "PMS" in cell `A1` that indicates the number of rows and therefore sheets to create. Starting in `A2` and down are all the names I want as the sheets that get created by copying the sheet contents of the sheet "Master".  I thought I had this, but am missing some knowledge obviously.

```vb
Sub TabMaker()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Cells(1, A)
    Debug.Print x
    For numtimes = 1 To x
        Debug.Print numtimes
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Copy _
          After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
        ActiveSheet.Name = PMS.Range("A" & x + 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing the worksheet name or index. Plus you need quotes around the `A`. `x = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("yoursheetname").Cells(1, "A")` or `x = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, "A")`, for example. You are also missing `Option Explicit` at the top of the module.

Comment: Thank you the code clears that now!   Now the other syntax I am having trouble getting right is on the 3rd last line:ActiveSheet.Name = PMS.Range("A" & x + 1)

Comment: `x + 1` never changes so you're trying to name multiple sheets with the same name. Did you mean to use `numtimes` instead of `x`?

Comment: Yes thanks, I found that error and changed it to numtimes, but it still breaking on that line  highlighting the row.  Error '424' Object required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of issues here

1. You've missed the reference to "PMS" in `x = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Cells(1, A)`
2. In the same line you're refereing to a non existant variable `A`
3. You've mixed up `x` and `NumTimes`
4. With `PMS.Range ...` you've refered to a sheet by it's Code Name, which will only work if you've changed that sheets' code name to "PMS", and the VBA code is located in the Active Workbook.

Here's your code, refactored

```vb
' Put this line at the top of your module
Option Explicit


Sub TabMaker()
    Dim NewSheetNum As Long
    Dim NumTimes As Long
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
    Dim wsPMS As Worksheet
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    
    Set wsMaster = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    Set wsPMS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PMS")
    
    NumTimes = wsPMS.Cells(1, 1)
    'Debug.Print NumTimes
    For NewSheetNum = 1 To NumTimes
        'Debug.Print NewSheetNum, "Of", NumTimes
        wsMaster.Copy After:=wsMaster
        Set NewSheet = ActiveSheet
        NewSheet.Name = wsPMS.Cells(NewSheetNum + 1, 1).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I really have to study VBA, I know just enough to get wrong 75% of the time!  Thank you - I actually want to swear but won't on this site! It worked PERFECTLY.  Thank you Chris and BigBen for your help.

Comment: Glad to help Tom..[Have you seen this?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Understood...now.  So I will do that.  One last question.  I have a cell (G1) in the master (and all the babys reading the tab name so it can fed to other formulae as a criteria. The formula that reads the tab name is:  =MID(CELL("Filename"),FIND("]",CELL("Filename"))+1,31).  Calculation is set to automatic.  When I go the copies of the work sheets G1 is always initially equal to the first tab name/number.  If resolves if I highlight it and then hit return or enter a number in a blank cell and hit return.  Is there a way to cause each worksheet to calculate once renamed?

Comment: There is a querk in`Cells` function that if you leave out the 2nd parameter, it refers to the active sheet, and doesn't do a volitile recalc.  Changing to `=MID(CELL("Filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("Filename",A1))+1,31)` should fix it